# Is there anyone successfully run RGBDSLAM

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everybody, Is there anyone successfully run RGBDSLAM. I carried out on the wiki installation.but i fail. Friend Can you share the successful installation of your success run RGBDSLAM experience it.If you share, please specify your operating environment.There are other things to note...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46257/is-there-anyone-successfully-run-rgbdslam/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-18**:
I managed to run successfully on Ros Fuerte, Ubuntu 12.04. You need to be more specific on your problem however, if you are seeking any help.

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-10-18**:
@yygyt  Hello, I want to know you complete the entire RGBDSLAM the complete process.I need to pay attention to what? Reference website is http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam?

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-18**:
Yes, of course. I can't say anything about paying attention. I mean install and build the package. If you have any problems please state it explicitly. State your system configuration too. Ubuntu, fuerte etc.. Otherwise I won't be able to help.

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-10-19**:
@yygyt my pc is ubuntu 11.10 64 bit .and i use ROS Fuerte too . and when i type: rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg    i got info :ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rgbdslam_freiburg
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuert

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-19**:
you seen this page? http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-10-19**:
@yygyt  i am confused . in the page http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/    he said when he type rosdep install rgbdslam . but in the wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam, there is no such command. just have rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg. is the wiki changed?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-10-21**:
rgbdslam_freiburg is the stack, rgbdslam is the package. it shouldn't matter much

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-10-21**:
Have you seen the command sequence at the bottom of rgbdslam's wiki page? I tried this sequence on a ubunut 11.10 and it worked fine. I'm also running it on ubuntu 12.04. It seems that you downloaded rgbdslam_freiburg into a folder that is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've added a [description for how to install ROS Fuerte and RGBDSLAM on Ubuntu from scratch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_Non-ROS_Users) to the wiki page. This was a test of the installation and worked for me without problems. I think it was a 64bit Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10, so it should work for you. If you are using a 32bit Ubuntu, I cannot guarantee anything, because I have none to test it on.
Good luck

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3